# Check if a user is deleted

Tags: slack-api

Im using the slack API with the python SDK.

Im trying to send a few messages to a few users and it seems `chat_postMessage` does not fail like I expected it to when trying to send a message to a deleted user.

So I need to do that check myself since I want to do something with the messages that were supposed to go to deleted users.

I saw this method: https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list but it forces me to "scrape" all the users which there are a lot of, and I might start running into rate limiting.

There is also this method: https://api.slack.com/methods/users.profile.get but I couldnt understand how it will behave for deleted users and it seems there is no indication in the response if its a deleted user or not (unfortunately I cant just test it myself right now).

So, to my question, is there a way to check if a user is deleted given a username? Or alternatively, make `chat_postMessage` fail for deleted users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `[users.info][1]` for a specific user using the user id. The response to this method has a `deleted` boolean that will hopefully help you.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be my only option, it is a bit of a bummer since I want to use a user's username and not user id, so I have to scrape all the users anyway to translate the username to the user id

Comment: You could also use the `users.lookupByEmail` method to search for individual users by their email if that helps! https://api.slack.com/methods/users.lookupByEmail